# pytables - how to speed retrieval of data in list

Tags: pytables

I have a query that returns ~ 1 million rows in the following format:

```
data = [[i['field1'], i['field2']] for i in tbl.where(conditions)]
```

and it is taking more than 5 mins.

When I tried `tbl.where(conditions)` by itself, the query took less than a second so most of the time seems to be spent iterating over the rows in the list comprehension.

Is there a faster way of retrieving field1/field2 from the query? (I have sufficient RAM to store the results in memory)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your "tbl" but here are some things I would look at:

1. Is your table using compression? `print tbl.filters.complevel`
2. Presuming your "conditions" are dependent upon the table fields have you created an index for these fields? `print tbl.indexedcolpathnames`
3. What if you use `idx = tbl.get_where_list(conditions)`, `tbl[:]['field1'][idx]`
4. If you have enough RAM, try opening your file in memory:
   `h5file = tables.open_file('myfile.h5', driver="H5FD_CORE")`
   `tbl = h5file.root.tbl` and see if that helps.